# Linking internal anchor text

Tags: seo, url, anchor

This might be a very stupid question but It bugs me so I have to get it out here:

Lets say on my websites blog page I have a link, I can either go:

```
<a href="index.php">homepage</a>
```

**My Question**

What if I go

```
<a href="http://www.example.org>homepage</a>
```

Here `example.org` is somesite.

What is the difference between the 2 linking methods above? Does Google see the 2 one as a link perhaps? What is best practice to do here in terms of linking?

Comment: Is "somesite" your own site or some other site?   The anchor text between your two links are identical, so your question title doesn't make much sense.     Your second link may have a typo in it -- it is missing a quote (unless you are asking about whether malformed markup changes SEO).

Comment: The start of the second anchor tag is malformed. there needs to be a quotation mark before the closing bracket. this means change `<a href="http://www.example.org>homepage</a>` to `<a href="http://www.example.org">homepage</a>`

Answer (score 1):

For SEO purposes use always absolute linking, like 
`<a href="http://www.example.org>homepage</a>`. And use always title attribute, which should correlate with the link anchor and, in best case, with the title+h1 of linked page.

On this way you ensure, that your site is correctly crawled and the crawler understands the meaning of each link and the meaning of realtions between pages.

Comment: For the record, Google always resolves all URLs to a full and complete URLs before processing and always has. So any relational URL, at least as Google sees it, will be resolved to a full URL. Still this advise is good because content can be scraped and mistakes made. I should be following it myself.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying `example.org` is not your site and goes to a different domain, then you'll get hit with a manual spam action at some point. You cannot mislead users as to where they're going. Being transparent in your anchor text and having a good internal link structure can help your SEO. The Penguin update by Google was an algorithm to prevent deceptive linking.

If you're saying you're using only `index.php` instead of the entire URL, then there is no preference one over the other. Just be transparent with the anchor text and have a good internal link structure.